# WCF authentication in partial(Meduiem) trust environment

Tags: security, wcf-binding

We are going to host an web application on a partial trust environment. In partial trust environment as you may know we can just use some of binding like Transport. We use SSL and chose Transport but it seems we can not use any of `HttpClientCredentialType` like Certificate. Using any of those is giving an exception of:

> "Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission failed".

I am not going to use any other `HttpClientCredentialType` like Windows or... As it is hosted on the cloud! I can not use Message security as well to make message authentication. If it is not possible to use any of those kind of credentials, do you know any other way to make authenticate clients who wants to invoke WCF methods?